# ASP.NET Core problem with request get parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, get

My application needs to accept parameters from a get request.

Everything works perfectly on localhost, but that's when I upload my site to the server when I try to make any request for example:

```
http://184.37.49.168/api/Data?example=1
```

I get "Page not found" for web address `http://184.37.49.168/api/Data?example=1`.

It says that I'm making a request for a url that doesn't exist, but I'm making a request with parameters.

What is the problem?

```
public class Stats
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    [FromQuery]
    public string Country {get; set; }
    [FromQuery]
    public string Video {get; set; }
    [Column (TypeName = "DateTime")]
    public DateTime Time {get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public void Get(Stats stat)
{
    if (Request.Query.Count != 0)
    {
        TimeZoneInfo rusTime = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Russian Standard Time");
        DateTime time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, rusTime);

        EntityContext context = new EntityContext();

        if (context.Stats.Any(e => e.Unique == stat.Unique))
        {
            var changeTimeUnique = context.Stats.Where(un => un.Unique == stat.Unique).FirstOrDefault();
            changeTimeUnique.Time = time;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Entry(stat).State = EntityState.Added;
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @memento, Where you deploy/Hosting the application, the Kestrel server, Nginx, Apache, or IIS?  And, please check your application configuration, is there any configurations for the production environment? Besides, perhaps the issue is related to the server Hosting configuration, try to access the website via the hostname.

Comment: Hello. i am hosting on ubuntu server with apache installed. All controllers work perfectly. But when I do get, it says that the page supposedly does not exist